# why am I getting a value greater than 1 as dice score

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have two segmented images, and I've computed the dice score using the formula below, however, I keep getting values greater than 1 (like 11.8, 12.8) as a dice score. is there a reason why? or is my approach for computing the dice score wrong?

```
def dice(X, Y): 
        intersection = (X * Y).sum()
        union = X.sum() + Y.sum()
        
        return ((2. * intersection) / (union))
```

Comment: If `X` and `Y` are not arrays with only values 0 and 1, then this can potentially lead to larger values. Check your input.

Comment: Yes, X and Y are normalised between 0 and 1 when the data is loaded. I checked the min and Max of X and Y after training and I see that its 0 and 24 respectively. I think this is due to some operations that I added during the training process. is It wise to **renormalise** my image to range between 0 and 1 (after training) before passing it to the dice function to calculate the score?

Comment: I don’t know if that’s wise because I don’t know what this data is, or how it’s transformed. To compute the dice score you need data between 0 and 1.